# How to fix Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'URL'

Tags: swift, multipartform-data, rx-swift

I am going to send data in formData format. However, an error such as the title occurred.

```
    func formData(_ api: URL, param: Parameters, img: String?) -> DataRequest {
            return AF.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                if img != nil {
                    multipartFormData.append(img, withName: "img", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                }
                for (key, value) in param {
                    multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key, mimeType: "text/plain")
                }
            }, to: baseURL + api.path(), method: .post, headers: api.header())
        }
```

This is the code I wrote.An error occurs in the if statement. Can you tell me if my code is correct or what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: img type error]
`multipartFormData.append()` should have received a data type, but you gave it a `String`